# Difference between ${} and {{}} in Maven pom.xml files

Tags: java, maven, variables, pom.xml

In a maven pom.xml I found this part:

```
<condextUrl>${artifactory.url}</contextUrl>
<username>{{artifactory.user}}</username>
```

What is the difference between `${}` and `{{}}`? What are the upsides/downsides to both syntaxes, and how do I set those variables?

Comment: First the `${..}` part is the default to define replacements the second one is something different `{{..}}` which is not supported by default only if explicitly configured Can you give more context where those entries have been used?

Comment: I had to take over a poorly maintained project by someone else and there is a few instances of that strewn all over the place in the pom.xml files. It is used in places where I'd expect variables to be used. E.g. for `{{registry.host}}`, `{{artifactory.user}}`, `{{JOB_NAME}}` or `{{BUILD_NUMBER}}`. Could be that they were mistakes, but that would be rather weird, since this syntax is used in multiple parts of the pom that should have been working. There are quite a few pom files and they are pretty huge and depend on each other, so posting all of that would be difficult.

Comment: Maybe it is totally unrelated, but google search bound the `{{}}` to jfrog, there is some connection with your project ?

Comment: @dariosicily The project is using JFrog, yes. That could make sense, thanks a lot! Do you have a link?

Comment: You are welcome,  the only I link I found is about [jfrog jira issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/NMAP-31/NMAP-31.html) where they talk about *In double curly brace expansions, maven pom properties are also ignored.*

Comment: Thats a bit of a lead, thank you!